# Add white space in the beginning and the end of a string

Tags: javascript

I want to add the white space in the beginning and the end of a string if there isn't.

If there is a whitespace at the beginning it will add at the end, and if there is at the end will add at the beginning

```
var string='This is test';
```

=>

```
var string=' This is test ';
```

or

```
var string='This is test ';
```

=> will only add at the beginning

```
var string=' This is test ';
```

Comment: what does you prevent to do so?

Comment: what have you tied so far ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code.

```
    var string='This is test ';
    var result = " "+string.trim()+" "; //trim will remove white space before and after string
    alert(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try with removing any possible whitespaces and add one on the beginning and end manually:

```
string = ' ' + string.trim() + ' '
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simple. Check below:

```js
let string ='This is test';
console.log(string); // No space
console.log(" " + string.trim() + " "); // space at start and end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex and capturing. ^\ |\ $|(^\ \ $) will match beginning space, ending space, and both: use accordingly